# Execute foreach loop in parallel or sequentially given a condition

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I often end up with several nested `foreach` loops and sometimes when writing general functions (e.g. for a package) there is no level which is obvious to parallelize at. Is there any way to accomplish what the mock-up below describes?

```
foreach(i = 1:I) %if(I < J) `do` else `dopar`% {
    foreach(j = 1:J) %if(I >= J) `do` else `dopar`% {
        # Do stuff
    }
}
```

Furthermore, is there some way to detect if a parallel backend is registered so I can avoid getting unnecessary warning messages? This would be useful both when checking packages prior to CRAN submission and to not bother users running R on single core computers.

```
foreach(i=1:I) %if(is.parallel.backend.registered()) `dopar` else `do`% {
    # Do stuff
}
```

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:** Thank you very much for all the feedback on cores and workers and you're right in that the best way to deal with the above example would be to rethink the whole setup. I'd prefer something like to below to the `triu` idea but it's essentially the same point. And it could of course also be done with a parallel `tapply` like Joris suggested.

```
ij <- expand.grid(i=1:I, j=1:J)
foreach(i=ij$I, j=ij$J) %dopar% {
    myFuction(i, j)
}
```

However, in my attempt to simplify the situation that gave rise to this thread I left out some crucial details. Imagine that I have two functions `analyse` and `batch.analyse` and the best level to parallelize at might be different depending on the values of `n.replicates` and `n.time.points`.

```
analyse <- function(x, y, n.replicates=1000){
    foreach(r = 1:n.replicates) %do% {
        # Do stuff with x and y
    }
}
batch.analyse <- function(x, y, n.replicates=10, n.time.points=1000){
    foreach(tp = 1:time.points) %do% {
        my.y <- my.func(y, tp)
        analyse(x, my.y, n.replicates)
    }
}
```

If `n.time.points > n.replicates` it makes sense to parallelize in `batch.analyse` but otherwise it makes more sense to parallelize in `analyse`. Any ideas on how to tackle it? Would it somehow be possible to detect in `analyse` if parallelization has already taken place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue that you raise was the motivation for the foreach nesting operator, '%:%'.  If the body of the inner loop takes a substantial amount of compute time, you're pretty safe using:

```
foreach(i = 1:I) %:%
    foreach(j = 1:J) %dopar% {
        # Do stuff
    }
```

This "unrolls" the nested loops, resulting in (I * J) tasks that can all be executed in parallel.

If the body of the inner loop doesn't take much time, the solution is more difficult.  The standard solution is to parallelize the outer loop, but that could still result in either many small tasks (when I is large and J is small) or a few large tasks (when I is small and J is large).

My favorite solution is to use the nesting operator with task chunking.  Here's a complete example using the doMPI backend:

```
library(doMPI)
cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
I <- 100; J <- 2
opt <- list(chunkSize=10)
foreach(i = 1:I, .combine='cbind', .options.mpi=opt) %:%
    foreach(j = 1:J, .combine='c') %dopar% {
        (i * j)
    }
closeCluster(cl)
```

This results in 20 "task chunks", each consisting of 10 computations of the loop body.  If you want to have a single task chunk for each worker, you can compute the chunk size as:

```
cs <- ceiling((I * J) / getDoParWorkers())
opt <- list(chunkSize=cs)
```

Unfortunately, not all parallel backends support task chunking.  Also, doMPI doesn't support Windows.

For more information on this topic, see my vignette "Nesting Foreach Loops" in the foreach package:

```
library(foreach)
vignette('nesting')
```

Comment: Wow, I stand in awe and am glad you joined SO! While I got you on the line, if you have a very time consuming task to perform is there a way to save partial results and resume later with the `foreach` package? To me that is the only missing piece to the perfect parallelization framework. If you have something that needs to be run for a week it is nice to stop every once in a while and see that you are on track.

Comment: @Backlin: There certainly isn't a checkpointing capability in foreach, but it's surprising how much you can do by writing your own iterators and combine functions.  If the iterator that is feeding the foreach loop is able to coordinate with the combine function, you could probably cobble together something of that sort.  I may try writing an example that demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure that I hadn't missed another semi-obvious thing. If you write a checkpointing example I'd be happy to see it, but it is fairly easy to do it manually.

Answer (score 6):

If you end up with several nested foreach loops, I'd rethink my approach. Using parallel versions of `tapply` can solve a lot of that hassle. In general, you shouldn't use nested parallelization, as that doesn't bring you anything. Parallelize the outer loop, and forget about the inner loop.

Reason is simple : if you have 3 connections in your cluster, the outer dopar loop will use all three. The inner dopar loop will not be able to use any extra connections, as there are none available. So you don't gain a thing. Hence, the mock-up you give doesn't make sense at all from a programming point of view.

Your second question is answered pretty easily by the function `getDoParRegistered()` which returns TRUE when a backend is registered, and FALSE otherwise. Pay attention though :

- it also returns TRUE if a sequential backend is registered (i.e. after calling registerDoSEQ).
- It will return TRUE as well after a cluster has been stopped, but in that case %dopar% will return an error.

eg :

```
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost",2),type="SOCK")
getDoParRegistered()
[1] FALSE
registerDoSNOW(cl)
getDoParRegistered()
[1] TRUE
stopCluster(cl)
getDoParRegistered()
[1] TRUE
```

But now running this code :

```
a <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
b <- t(a)
foreach(b=iter(b, by='col'), .combine=cbind) %dopar%
  (a %*% b)
```

will return in an error :

```
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

You could build an extra check. A (hideously ugly) hack you can use to check that the connection registered by `doSNOW` is valid, can be :

```
isvalid <- function(){
    if (getDoParRegistered() ){
      X <- foreach:::.foreachGlobals$objs[[1]]$data
      x <- try(capture.output(print(X)),silent=TRUE)
      if(is(x,"try-error")) FALSE else TRUE
    } else {
      FALSE
    }
}
```

Which you could use as

```
if(!isvalid()) registerDoSEQ()
```

This will register the sequential backend if getDoParRegistered() returns TRUE but there is no valid cluster connection any longer. But again, this is a hack, and I have no idea if it works with other backends or even other types of cluster types (I use sockets mostly).

Comment: Good stuff.  Also `getDoParWorkers()` will return the # of registered workers.

Comment: @Iterator : True, but not necessary here. if a backend is registered, I take it the user knows what he/she is doing. If not, registerDoSEQ() takes the safe way out. All of this will be different if one is using a different backend, eg doMC, doSMP, ...

Answer (score 3):

In reverse order of the questions you asked:

1. @Joris is correct regarding checking for a registered parallel backend.  However, note that there is a difference between a machine being single core and whether or not a parallel backend is registered.  Checking the # of cores is a very platform (operating system) specific task.  On Linux, this may work for you:

   ```
   CountUnixCPUs  <- function(cpuinfo = "/proc/cpuinfo"){
   tmpCmd  <- paste("grep processor ", cpuinfo, " | wc -l", sep = "")
   numCPU  <- as.numeric(system(tmpCmd, intern = TRUE))
   return(numCPU)
   }
   ```

   Edit: See @Joris's link to another page, below, which gives advice for Windows and Linux.  I will likely rewrite my own code, at least to include more options for counting cores.
2. Regarding the nested loops, I take a different tack: I prepare a table of parameters and then iterate over rows.  A very simple way is, e.g.:

   ```
   library(Matrix)
   ptable <- which(triu(matrix(1, ncol = 20, nrow = 20))==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
   foreach(ix_row = 1:nrow(ptable)) %dopar% { myFunction(ptable[ix_row,])}
   ```

Comment: By the way, if there is any way to determine the # of available cores from within in R, I would be *very* interested in knowing that.  It doesn't appear to be supported by `.Platform`, `.Machine`, or `Sys.info()`.

Comment: Don't know if that's going to get you far. On a single-core, you can still register multiple workers. I don't even know if that many single-core computers are sold these days...

Comment: @Joris: you're right - anyone can go nuts and have more workers than cores.  I always check the # of cores first, before setting the # of workers.  As for single core computers being sold, they're all over: iPhone, Android devices, even Microsoft is backing these single core machines with "telephone" capabilities.  ;-)  Imagine: R in your pocket!

Comment: then take a look at : http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Programmaticly-finding-number-of-processors-by-R-code-td2953437.html

Comment: @Joris: Love it, thanks!  I didn't know about `Sys.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")` for Windows.  The `multicore::detectCores()` functionality should be a fine substitute for Linux.  Adding this to my code now...