# doParallel not returning anything in R

Tags: r, foreach

Here is the structure of this section of my code:

```
 x <- foreach(i=1:n) %dopar%
 {
    #dostuff, n=32

    for(i in 1:m)
    {
       #do complicated stuff that results in a vector of m rows,m large
    }
 }
```

and I wish that x would then be a mxn matrix. It's super important that each core is given a subset of n because everything from there has to run sequentially. From that point they will run nearly the same speed but it is not assured.

Unfortunately I get: Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection

For what it's worth, I'm fairly certain it's doing the (many!) operations. It takes about as long as I expect for various parameters outside of this section of code.

Comment: This post might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872077/execute-foreach-loop-in-parallel-or-sequentially-given-a-condition

Comment: I think my problem is slightly different. The way the inner loop is structured, it's actually FAR faster to have it operate that on a single core than it would be to parallelize it. The reason is that I'm solving a linear program and then changing only a little bit for each increase of the index. As such, I can use a faster algorithm for LPs...

Comment: You need a return value in the expression you give to `foreach`. `for` returns an invisible `NULL` (see `help("for")`). Have you checked if your loop runs in serial? Also, how did you register the parallel backend?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I rewrote my code to be a function instead. My function optimize(D) returns a vector of length m, and I've verified that this works correctly.

The rest of my program is now just 

foreach(D=1:Monte_Carlo_Sims,.packages='clpAPI', .combine = "cbind") %dopar%
{
  optimize(D)
}

but I still get the same error

Comment: I have figured it out...writing it as a function is what did it for me (and then I just had a minor syntax error)